# Timed 3 Bars CSS Menu

Tags: css, css-transitions, hamburger-menu

I am trying to make a burger menu where the three bars fill with an orange color from left to right on hover!

Currently though I have it that when you hover, the bars fully fill with orange, and when you hover away, the bars fill with white from the right to the left!

Here is my code:

```css
#burger-box     {
  float:right;
  width:80px;  
  height:70px;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background:rgba(34,34,34,1);
  position:fixed;
  z-index:101}
#burger-box > #cpBtn {
  width:40%;
  height:25px;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:25px 30% 20px 30%
}
#burger-box > #cpBtn > div {
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:2px;
  background:#fff;
  background:linear-gradient(to left, #fff 50%, #E18767 50%);
  background-size:200% 100%;
  background-position:right bottom;
  margin:6px 0;
  transition:background 1.75s ease
}
#burger-box > #cpBtn > div:hover {
  background:#E18767
 }
#burger-box > #cpBtn:hover > div {
  background:#E18767;
  background-position:left bottom
}
```

```html
<section id="burger-box">
  <div id="cpBtn">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>  
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/0g3n1bkh/

If that's the case then the problem was that `background-gradients` are not animatable.

```css
#burger-box {
  float: right;
  width: 80px;
  height: 70px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 1);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101
}
#burger-box > #cpBtn {
  width: 40%;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 25px 30% 20px 30%
}
#burger-box > #cpBtn > div {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #fff 50%, #E18767 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: background 1.75s ease
}
#burger-box > #cpBtn:hover > div {
  background-position: left bottom
}
```

```html
<section id="burger-box">
  <div id="cpBtn">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Just add the following to your CSS:

```
#burger-box > #cpBtn > div {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
#burger-box > #cpBtn > div:first-child {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
#burger-box > #cpBtn > div:last-child {
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

Comment: I am just wondering if it's possible to stagger the timing on the three bars at all using :first-child & :last-child with transition delay?

Comment: To stagger the timing only when the orange bars slide in add `:hover` to `#cpBtn`

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the Fiddle above to include timed functions for the three bars using the nth-child()
Here is my code:

```
<section id="burger-box">
  <div id="cpBtn">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>  
</section>
#burger-box {
  float: right;
  width: 80px;
  height: 70px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 1);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101
}
#burger-box > #cpBtn {
  width: 40%;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 25px 30% 20px 30%
}
#burger-box > #cpBtn > div {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #fff 50%, #E18767 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: background .25s ease .45s
}
#burger-box > #cpBtn > div:nth-child(1) {
  transition: background .25s ease .25s
}
#burger-box > #cpBtn > div:nth-child(3) {
  transition: background .25s ease .65s
}
#burger-box > #cpBtn:hover > div {
  background-position: left bottom
}
```

And the js fiddle is [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/0g3n1bkh/23/)